# How to set a class only to a current object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a reservation system in which the date of the reservation is set by `DateFrom` - `DateTo` properties range. Now I want to assign the `.alert` class to those reservations, which are about to expire (1 day to expiration).

The problem is that If a reservation is about to expire, not only this reservation has `.alert` class set but also all other reservations, so all `<tr>` are red even though only one is supposed to. How to bind It only to current reservation?

**Condition**

```
  foreach(Reservation r in res)
        {
            bool varovani;
            if (r.DateTo.AddDays(-1).Day <= DateTime.Now.Day)
            {
                varovani = true;

            }
            else
            {
                varovani = false;
            }
            ViewBag.Varovani = varovani;
        }
```

**Table in View**

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach (Reservation r in Model)
    {
        string alertClass = "";
        if (ViewBag.Varovani == true)
        {
            alertClass = "danger";
        }
        else
        {
            alertClass = "";
        }
        <tr class="@alertClass">

            <td>@r.Reserved.Id</td>
            <td>@r.Name</td>
            <td>@r.DateFrom</td>
            <td>@r.DateTo</td>
            <td>

                   @Ajax.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", "Skies", new { id = r.Reserved.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "modalContent", OnBegin = "openModalWindow" })

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Reservation", new { id = r.Id }, null)
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Reservation", new { id = r.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Přejete si opravdu smazat tuto výpujčku? " + r.Name + "');" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
</tbody>
```

Comment: You are setting the class based on the ViewBag item's value which means it ends up happening for everything.  You need to set it based on just that one reservation.  I would add a property to the `Reservation` viewmodel and then detect it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `ViewBag.Varovani` is a single bool value.  So every time you iterate through you overwrite the "Varovani" `bool` value. What you want to do is add a property to you `Reservation` class:

```
public class Reservation
{ 
    //Rest of class

    public bool Varovani => DateTo.AddDays(-1).Day <= DateTime.Now.Day;
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (Reservation r in Model)
{
    <tr class="@(r.Varovani ? "danger" : "")">
        <td>@r.Reserved.Id</td>
        <td>@r.Name</td>
        <td>@r.DateFrom</td>
        <td>@r.DateTo</td>
        <td>
               @Ajax.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", "Skies", new { id = r.Reserved.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "modalContent", OnBegin = "openModalWindow" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Reservation", new { id = r.Id }, null)
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Reservation", new { id = r.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Přejete si opravdu smazat tuto výpujčku? " + r.Name + "');" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Alternatively you could perform the logic in your view (although I would not recommend it unless you cannot modify the `Reservation` class):

```
@foreach (Reservation r in Model)
{
    string alertClass = "";
    if (r.DateTo.AddDays(-1).Day <= DateTime.Now.Day)
    {
        alertClass = "danger";
    }
    else
    {
        alertClass = "";
    }

    //Rest of your original Razor
```

**Disclaimer** 
I have no idea what "Varovani" means, so only use that as your property name if it describes your logic properly.

Comment: Perfect! And varovaní means warning in english, sorry for that.